# Firefox requests the master password twice

Tags: firefox, passwords

I've set a master password for Firefox. When Firefox starts, it strangely opens two separate password request windows. When I type in the master password and hit enter, Firefox opens without problems, but the other password request window stays there. I simply close it but it's annoying. Why are there 2 windows as it's enough to type the password once? I've upgraded Firefox from 3.5.5 to 3.5.6 but the problem remains. Any comments?

---

**PS:**
<sub><s>The latest news from this issue can be followed from [the related Mozilla Support Forum](https://support.mozilla.com/en-US/forum/1/528999).</s></sub>

The problem re-emerged when I downgraded Firefox from v4 to v3.6.16. Then the new version (3.6.17) was released, I upgraded to that version, and the problem was solved.

Comment: Yes, a blank tab opens when I open Firefox.

Comment: I've only had this happen when updating a component that tries to open a "what's new" page on restart, or sometimes Xmarks (Foxmarks) being too eager.  Seems like you're not alone though, so I'd keep an eye on this thread: http://support.mozilla.com/tiki-view_forum_thread.php?locale=en-US&comments_parentId=528999&forumId=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A possible workaround is to use: [Startup Master](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/9808) - A Firefox Addon.

The issue may be that some addon is trying to access a site for which you have saved your login credentials in the password manager. Hence when it tries to access the site, it prompts for a password. (may be 2 addons doing that the same time)

Comment: As per what I know, everytime firefox encounters a website for which it has credentials stored, it will popup a master password box. You can simulate it by starting firefox & open Orkut & Facebook in two separate tabs.

Comment: This addon no longer exists. Firefox Quantum 66 still shows two dialog boxes.