# Password prompt appearing twice in Firefox at startup

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 with Firefox 9.0.1 with a couple of addons. Ocasionally when I start Firefox two prompts asking for the password appear. Any solution?

[image]

Comment: isn't that password asked by your password manager? like when you first connect to the internet?

Comment: What about if you disable all the add-ons?

Comment: Do you know the master password and does it accept it ok?

Comment: The password is prompted because `master password` is set in FF and some addon requires a password. It's not for the internet. The problem happens occasionally, so don't know if it happens with addons disabled or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox requests the master password twice](https://superuser.com/questions/86096/firefox-requests-the-master-password-twice)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and fiddled with the extensions.

When I remove the "Firefox Ubuntu extension", the password is only asked once.
I personally don't care about Ubufox extension (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226/what-does-the-ubuntu-firefox-modifications-extension-to-firefox-do) for what it does).

Hence, until the issue is fixed, a solution is to disable the extension.

Answer (score 0):

If I open an old Firefox session where I had multiple tabs open that required credentials (which are stored in the master key store) I not only get 2 of those prompts, but sometimes 5.

The problem is simple really. A tab requests stored credentials from the key store and Firefox notices that you haven't provided the master key yet, so it prompts you to provide it.
The next tab does the same thing and so on. Maybe you're also using Sync, there's another thing requesting credentials.

Why, after so many years, this behavior still results in multiple, stacked password prompts is beyond me. I would assume it has to be like that due to security concerns.